# creating a "export to eclipse" feature. where can I get the project files specifications?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in a small java editor and I want to add a feature to export a project to a eclipse java project format. I know I have to create a .project and .classpath files. I would like to know where I can find information of what kind of information these files can store. I have checked some files from projects but it's difficult to get all the possiblities from a few examples.

I have tried to search for the specification, but I didnt find it. Does anyone knows where can I find such information (besides eclipse source code) ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304288/creating-a-export-to-eclipse-feature-where-can-i-get-the-project-files-specifi/4304303#4304303), Maven Eclipse plugin does that kind of thing. You should have a look at its source, especially [EclipseClasspathWriter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/eclipse/writers/EclipseClasspathWriter.html) and [EclipseProjectWriter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/eclipse/writers/EclipseProjectWriter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create a maven project instead and invoke "mvn eclipse:eclipse".

Comment: That's what I would have suggested (+1). Alternatively, have a look at the maven eclipse plugin's source code and do what they do.